# python regex to match characters and numbers together

Tags: python, regex

I need a pattern to match characters between numbers, what should I define as a pattern to match characters and number together?

example string(the Bold string is what I should match):

IP/51-0000523b      ivr                  s                   2 Up      BackGround   **5230f668473bd**/MainIVR     4566658     00:00:22`                         (None)

IP/51-0000523b      ivr                  s                   2 Up      BackGround   **dh234926b9900**/MainIVR     4566658     00:00:22`                         (None)

IP/51-0000523b      ivr                  s                   2 Up      BackGround   **l23423y98t232**/MainIVR     4566658     00:00:22`                         (None)

IP/51-0000523b      ivr                  s                   2 Up      BackGround   **5230f668473bd**/MainIVR     4566658     00:00:22`                         (None)

Comment: Can you be more precise? What exactly do you want to match? How are start and end of a match defined? Do there have to be both letters and digits, or is one of the two enough? Any other restrictions? Like "only ASCII digits/letters" instead of "all Unicode letters/digits"?

Comment: edited my answer so you can extract just the bold characters from the strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters *between* numbers would be `(?<=\d)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\d)` (i. e. only those characters which are directly embraced by numbers, so for `abc234def678hij` it would be `def`), but I have the feeling you mean characters and numbers together; that would be `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` plain and simple.

Comment: yes I mean characters and numbers together. thanks alot It works

Comment: The `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` will also match `0000523b` in the example above. I'm not sure if that's what you intended.

Comment: That's right, @IceArdor.

Comment: no, I have a space charecter befor that match, so It works for me

Answer (score 0):

well if what you want is to see if one of your strings is contained in one of your other strings, that's pretty simple.

```
import re

strsToTest = ["5230f668473bd","dh234926b9900","l23423y98t232","ju9898qr9898g"]
containedIn = "IP/51-0000523b ivr s 2 Up BackGround 5230f668473bd/MainIVR 4566658 00:00:2"
strsMatched = []
for s in strsToTest:
    if(re.search(s, containedIn)) :
    strsMatched.append(s)
print strsMatched
```

could have just been

```
strsToTest = ["5230f668473bd","dh234926b9900","l23423y98t232","ju9898qr9898g"]
containedIn = "IP/51-0000523b ivr s 2 Up BackGround 5230f668473bd/MainIVR 4566658 00:00:2"
strsMatched = []
for s in strsToTest:
    if(s in containedIn) strsMatched.append(s)
printStrsMatched
```

if what you want to do is to extract the bold strings, then

```
import re

strs = ["IP/51-0000523b ivr s 2 Up BackGround 5230f668473bd/MainIVR 4566658 00:00:22`", "IP/51-0000523b ivr s 2 Up BackGround dh234926b9900/MainIVR 4566658 00:00:22`"]#etc
results = []
for s in strs:
    m = re.match(".*BackGround\s(\w+)/.*",s)
    results.append(m.groups(1));
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say `given_string` contain entire string

```
all_numbers = re.findall(' (\S+)/Main', str)
```

Simple !